# Newbie Problem: C/C++ with Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

My setup includes:
Windows Vista, Eclipse 3.5.0, and gdb, make, gcc 3.4.4, g++ 3.4.4 enabled through Cygwin, and environmental variable is already set.

My FIRST problem is that I can run and build an application like the information in Console:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project HelloWorld ****

make all <br />
Building file: ../src/HelloWorld.cpp <br />
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Compiler <br />
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/HelloWorld.d" <br /> -MT"src/HelloWorld.d" -o"src/HelloWorld.o" "../src/HelloWorld.cpp" <br />
Finished building: ../src/HelloWorld.cpp <br />

Building target: HelloWorld.exe <br />
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker <br />
g++  -o"HelloWorld.exe"  ./src/HelloWorld.o  <br />  
Finished building target: HelloWorld.exe <br />
```

But in the Problems view, I still have the following warnings,

```
Error launching external scanner info generator (g++ -E -P -v -dD F:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.cpp) <br />
Error launching external scanner info generator (g++ -E -P -v -dD F:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.cpp) <br />
Error launching external scanner info generator (gcc -E -P -v -dD F:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.c)   <br />
Error launching external scanner info generator (gcc -E -P -v -dD F:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.c)
```

My SECOND problem is that I have set up PATH but I cannot run '`g++ --version`' and '`gcc --version`' in the windows command, while 'make', 'gdb', 'gcc-3', and 'g++-3' work.
Does anyone know what I can do to fix those problems? Is the second problem related to the first problem?

Thanks

Hank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is sure is your second problem could very well be related to your first issue:
From [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg07992.html):

> Make sure gcc is installed and on the system PATH.

This [other thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg08782.html) states the obvious:

> a `PATH` env var change via the OS GUI won't take effect in an already running app (Eclipse), including an already open console window.
> If you're re-launching Eclipse after the PATH change, you're not doing so from an existing console window, right?
> Also, try copying the `gcc.exe` executable to `c:\WINNT` just as a test. It won't work from there stand-alone, but you should at least see some difference that will help you determine if your problem is indeed a PATH one.

For, cygwin environment, other [hacks](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg18472.html) are [possible](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg18401.html):

> - Recent versions of Cygwin no longer have gcc.exe or g++.exe. These files have been replaced with .lnk files that point to gcc-3.exe and g++-3.exe (or whatever)
> - Some tools in Eclipse need to launch "gcc" or "g++" to generate some sort of info. The OS cannot find gcc.exe or g++.exe and so it returns an error.
> - I have found that the following procedure works for me:
>   1/ delete gcc.exe.lnk and g++.exe.lnk from cygwin/bin
>   2/ Copy gcc-3.exe to gcc.exe
>   3/ Copy g++-3.exe to g++.exe

---

Be aware though there:

- is an [opened bug (221992)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=221992) reporting of this message popping up at various intervals.
- is a fixed bug about [(225272) Problems with spawner and fast (Dual Core) machines](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=225272) which can influence this issue (so what version of CDT are you using? I suspect you are not concerned by this one)
- one solution if the problem really persists would be to [replace the spawner.dll with an earlier version (from CDT 4.0.3)](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg16760.html)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. The problem is solved! As I am sure the PATH is set, I started following these three steps to solve the Cygwin's naming problem. And it worked for me. The warnings are gone, and I can run 'gcc' and 'g++' in the windows command.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Replacing g++ and gcc files in \cygwin\bin with NTFS hardlinks resolves this problem for me, too.